# Determining whether a number is a perfect square without computing its square root

Tags: computability, decision-problem, number-theory

One of the interesting results of Number Theory is the theory of quadratic reciprocity. One finds that it is possible to determine whether an equation $x^2 \equiv a \pmod p$ has a solution $x$ without computing its solution.

Is it possible to do the same with the equation $x^2=a$, determine whether $a$ is a perfect square without computing its square root?

Comment: You can use a probabilistic approach, see [this answer on mathoverflow](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1360053/9020).

Comment: Yes, that's true. I didn't think of that. I was curious about deterministic approaches.